# Is there a standard notation for the function $F:2^X \to 2^Y$ defined as $F(S) = \{f(x)|x\in S\}$?

Tags: functions, notation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Notation for image and preimage](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109942/notation-for-image-and-preimage)

Is there a standard notation for the function $F$?

$f:X\to Y$, define $F:2^X \to 2^Y$ as $F(S) = \{f(x)|x\in S\}$.

Recently I have to define this kind of function very often, and wonder there are already notations for this.

Comment: In some fields, one would write ${\rm map} f$ for $F$. It occurs to me that if you stated up front that you were going to write ${\mathcal P}(f)$  or ${\mathcal P}f$ for this, nobody would complain.

Comment: Since you’re using $2^X$ for the power set of $X$, you could establish a convention that if $f:X\to Y$, then $2^f:2^X\to 2^Y:S\mapsto f[S]$.

Comment: @Brian: That seems more likely to confuse than not. In general, given a function $f : X \to Y$, one gets a map of function spaces $Z^f : Z^Y \to Z^X$ going the other way!

Comment: I feel like in some category theory contexts, this is either referred to as $f^*$ or $f_*$, but I've forgotten which.

Comment: @Zhen Lin: If you say so: I’ve never seen the notation. (And on first exposure don’t much care for it, for whatever that may be worth.)

Comment: @Thomas: Upper stars indicate contravariance. Some people would write $f_*$ for this. I would write $f_!$, because $f_!$ is left adjoint to $f^* = f^{-1}$.

Comment: Maybe a modified version of Brian's suggestion: ${_2}f$...maybe chemists prefer this one.